# Check if method exists in a class in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am having a class in which a method currently doesn't exists but will be added later. I want to use that method if it exists otherwise not.
For eg.

```
Class A {
    public func(string s) {
        // Currently this method is not present in Class A
    }
}
```

I want to check that if this method exists, then call it, otherwise do something else. I found a solution which works for JavaScript but doesn't work for TypeScript:

```
let objectOfA = new A();
if ( objectOfA.func === function) {
    objectOfA.func();
}
```

But this somehow doesn't works in TypeScript and throws compilation error saying `Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'string' and '() => any'`.

Is there a way I can check for method existence in TypeScript?

Comment: Just comment out the function call as long as the function isn't implemented yet.

Comment: @Cerbrus Actually I want to check-in my code which should work before/ after implementation of the non-existent function.

Comment: @Cerbrus Why is this closed as dublicate? This question is about TypeScrtipt and that one is about JS. TypeScript does add quite a bit of difficulty. If you try to check if non-existant function exists then the tools will yell that "such field doens't exist, don't do it" which exactly what you check. However when you override a method that may or may not be implemented it makes sence to check if its ancesor exists.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator to get the ty the of the operand. Although use bracket notation to get unknown properties(to avoid throwing exception).

```
let objectOfA = new A();
if ( typeof objectOfA['func'] === 'function') {
    objectOfA.func();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still throws compilation error saying "Property  'func' does not exist on type 'A'."

Comment: Yes I tried that. It still shows the same error.

Comment: @ParagGangil : try `typeof objectOfA['func'] === 'function'` .... you need to use bracket notation

Comment: This solution gives me error TS7053 - "Element implicitly has an 'any' type".